# Ayuda!! Implementar una vista tipo diálogo parecida a los comentarios de Facebook en su app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

me gustaría saber cómo se llama la vista que implementa facebook en su app para Android y como la puedo implementar, muchas gracias de antemano. [Está es la vista que ando buscando](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PCglL.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

¡Hola amigo!
Aquí tienes la respuesta a tu pregunta. Yo hice esta implementación y queda realmente bien. ¡Espero que te sea de gran ayuda! 
[Show PopUp Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34194097/4682937)

Comment: Hola JKY, gracias por aportar. Sin embargo no es una respuesta de calidad ya que solo es un enlace. Si la respuesta a la que referencias se perdiera, esta respuesta no tendria sentido. Mejor es que expliques aqui lo que se explica en la otra respuesta , y obviamente referenciando de donde salio la informacion. Mira [answer] para mejorarla. Un saludo